# Create wrapper around interface and get method/paramters called

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

Lets say I have this interface

```
public interface ITest
{
    int Property1 { get; set; }
    void Method1();
    string GetMethod1();
    void MethodWithParam(string str);
}
```

How can I create a wrapper object around this?

And then capture the methods called or paramters and values accessed etc.

For example:

```
var myWrapper = GetWrapper<ITest>();
myWrapper.Property1 = 7;
```

How would I be able to using reflection or whatever to know the following:

> Paramter name being called and value being set

```
var data = myWrapper.GetMethod1("Test");
```

> Get method name of "GetMethod1" along with paramaters and then return a value based on that?

Hope makes sense

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through wrapping this?

Comment: Basically. A generic wrapper which takes any interface you give it. And calls an external API (yet to be built) with what is being accessed. So in above example if I call myWrapper.GetMethod1("Test"). I am then going to pass following data:
Method - GetMethod1
Paramaters - "Test". Then get response back and return this

Comment: And if call myWrapper.Property1 = 7. I want to know property name and value being set to pass to API.

Comment: You may look into template (or generic types in .net).

Comment: I know what a generic type is. But this isnt what im asking help about.

Comment: I was thinking something like how nsubstitue works. https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/ it allows you to mock an interface. but begind the scenes, I need to be able to get the method names being called or paramter names and values being set etc...

Comment: What you need is this http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/

Comment: Looking through nsub code let me to this. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so answer quite simple using Castle Core proxy generator:
https://github.com/castleproject/Core

```
public interface ITest
{
    int Property1 { get; set; }
    void Method1();
    string GetMethod1();
    void MethodWithParam(string str);
}

public static class Wrapper
{
    private class MethodInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        Action<IInvocation> OnIntercept;
        public MethodInterceptor(Action<IInvocation> OnIntercept)
        {
            this.OnIntercept = OnIntercept;
        }

        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            OnIntercept?.Invoke(invocation);
        }
    }

    private static void CallAPI(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methodName = invocation.Method.Name;
        var valuespassed = invocation.Arguments;
        var retType = invocation.Method.ReturnType.FullName;

        //DO API THINGS NOW
    }

    public static T Get<T>()
    {
        ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var interceptor = new MethodInterceptor(CallAPI);
        var c = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<ITest>(interceptor);
        return (T)c;
    }
}




public class Test123
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var c = Wrapper.Get<ITest>();
        c.Property1 = 7;
        var propval = c.Property1;
    }
}
```

Any action on c calls the intercept function where can get everything from method name being called to arguments passed.